# Datetime split and find the time difference between each row

Tags: python

[image]

I have a datetime data in the dataframe format for 1000s of rows like this and I need to find the time delta between successive rows. But, unfortunately, I can't seem to find a way to split and use datetime module to collect this information.

Looked for using datatime module, but can't seem to find the correct way to split the data and find the time difference.

Comment: Are those strings?  What have you tried?  All it takes is `df['date'].apply` with `to_datetime`.  You can see the column is `%Y%m%d%H%M%S`.

Answer (score 1):

I write some motivations for my answer below. Feel free to check out **Answer** to skip all this.

**Exploration**

So to simulate your data, I use the following code:

```
vals = ['20231116032619','20231116032640','20231116032641','20231116032644','20231116032646','20231116032648','20231116032650','20231116032652','20231116032654','20231116032656','20231116032659']

data = {"date": vals}
df = pd.DataFrame(data)
```

I'm assuming the values in your column is expressed as strings (objects). If these are ints, we might want to convert each row value into a string using [astype](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.astype.html).

I'm also assuming that the strings  represents year, month, day, hour, minute, and second. For example `20231116032640` represents `November 16, 2023 03:26:40".

First off, we would want to convert this column to the appropriate `datetime` object using the [to_datetime](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.to_datetime.html) method.

Once we complete this, we could easily get the difference between a datetime value and its previous row datetime simply using subtraction, the [shift](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.shift.html) method, and lastly some datetime unit of measure such as [.dt.seconds](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.Series.dt.seconds.html).

In terms of pseudocode, this would be something along the lines of:

```
convert date to datetime
delta = (date column - shift 1 back).seconds
```

| delta(sec) |
| --- |
| 21 |
| 1 |
| ... |

**Answer**

Putting this all together, we could write out something like:

```
df["date"] = pd.to_datetime(df["date"], format="%Y%m%d%H%M%S")
delta = (df["dates"] - df["dates"].shift(1)).dt.seconds
```

This results in a `NaN` value in the first-row, but this could be easily handled.

| delta(sec) |
| --- |
| NaN |
| 21.0 |
| 1.0 |
| 3.0 |
| 2.0 |
| 2.0 |
| ... |

Hope this helps! Happy coding.